# Let's vote! A project to bring some recognition to neglected content

Tags: discussion, voting

There are currently [**25,412** questions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ano) on Web Applications that are not closed or deleted.

Of those, [**3,979**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ano+answers%3A0) have no answers at all.

Worse, I think, is that there are [**2,872**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ano+answers%3A1+isanswered%3A0) questions with answers, none of which have a positive score. (Even worse, about a third of these have *accepted* answers!)

I find it difficult to believe that almost 3,000 questions have answers and that *none* of them are useful.

So here's what I suggest:

- Go to the Question list for [Questions with answers but none have a positive score](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ano+answers%3A1+isanswered%3A0)
- Choose some questions where you have an interest/some experience/a bit of expertise
- ***Vote!***

  - Upvote stuff that's good. Downvote the garbage. Vote for questions too, while you're at it.

    - Of course, if something is "meh", don't vote at all.
- While you're there, clean stuff up. Edit for spelling and grammar. Remove meta tags. Fix formatting.
- Or, if the answer(s) there are inadequate, add your own!

You get 30 votes (plus 10 extra for questions) every day. Use them!

*What's in it for the people who do this?*
[A badge](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/badges/193/suffrage). Maybe [two](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/badges/202/vox-populi) (or [more](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty)). Plus the satisfaction of making the site better.

*What's in it for the people whose posts get voted on?*
For the ones that get upvotes, a signal that their contribution is valuable and that we'd like them to contribute more. (For those that get downvotes, a signal that their stuff isn't up to snuff; we'd like posts that are more useful.)

*What's in it for Web Applications?*
More good content filters to the top. Bad content gets pushed down (and maybe disappeared). The site becomes more valuable as a result. Voting is also important because it helps automated management of the site work better.

### Breakdown by tag of questions with answers but none have a positive score

#### Top Five by total number of questions

- [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ano+answers%3A1+isanswered%3A0+%5Bgoogle-sheets%5D):
  1190 / 5267
- [gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ano+answers%3A1+isanswered%3A0+%5Bgmail%5D):
  234 / 3813
- [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ano+answers%3A1+isanswered%3A0+%5Bfacebook%5D):
  201 / 2985
- [youtube](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ano+answers%3A1+isanswered%3A0+%5Byoutube%5D):
  111 / 1192
- [google-apps-script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3Ano+answers%3A1+isanswered%3A0+%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D):
  273 / 1173

Related:

- [Is there a lack of voting on Web Applications?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1105/354)

Comment: Thanks for spearheading this, Al.

Comment: Yeah, well, it's only resulted in 5 people with more than 11 votes so far this week, so...

Comment: There are some new faces in the monthly counts, so I'm hopeful.

Comment: I'm slowly but surely working my way through them, upvoting well-worded, usable answers and questions.

Comment: @pnuts: re:exclude questions where all answers have negative score. No, I'm afraid it's not really possible with the search interface. It would _probably_ be doable with the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @pnuts: I regularly run through this list. An awful lot of the time, the only answer available is mine, and I obviously can't vote on those. I do vote on good answers I find. I could, perhaps, do it more often, but this is an attempt to get _more_ people voting, not just generate more votes.