# What we should do with formula-screenshot only answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

In the last year we got a lot of answers that include only a formula and a screenshot to [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) questions. I just found an [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/131035/88163) to [FILTER(condition OR condition) syntax?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/42428/88163)
 that include two formulas and a screenshot of each of them. Here is the current content of this answer:

> ```
> =FILTER(A:F, REGEXMATCH(A:A, "Combat
> Medic|Universal"))
> ```
>
> [image: 0] I
>
> ---
>
> ```
> =QUERY(A:F, " where A matches 'Combat Medic|Universal'",
> 0)
> ```
>
> [image: 0]

As you can see, there isn't any description that explains the formulas and how they answer the question.

While in this case there is an older answer that has a high score (>40), there are many other cases were a formula-screenshot answer having a 0 score is the only answer to the question.

Some possible actions

1. Downvote
2. Leave a comment

   <sup>In the referred case it's almost useless as the answer author is banned until August 2020.</sup>
3. Vote to delete
4. Add another answer including the same or a similar formula but including an explanation
5. Flag to ♦ moderators attention
6. Do nothing

Related

- [Let's vote! A project to bring some recognition to neglected content](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3712/88163)

Comment: Best option is 4 : The formula and screenshot is useful for advanced people who can use and adapt it to their needs without additionnal help. A more elaborate answer with explanation is useful for the less experienced users.

Comment: Flagging is not the best option.  I'm not sure what to do with them either.  Many showed up in the LQ review, but they did answer the question at hand, so I was hesitant to delete them outright.  I would say edit any that merit more explanation if you come across them, especially if someone has asked for clarification in the comments and was never addressed.